# Android ListView: multiple и single группы одновременно

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте!

*Делаю своё первое приложение, никогда и ни разу не писал ещё вопросы, всё находил через интернет, сделано уже очень много, но с этой проблемой справиться не могу. Уже без вранья неделю сижу и мучаюсь. Решил всё-таки просить помощи.*

Есть `ListView`, в котором присутствуют группы элементов: заголовок группы и непосредственно `Checkable`-элементы списка. Вся сложность в том, что мне не подходит режим выбора `multipleChoice` или `singleChoice`, так как у меня есть группы элементов и такие, и такие.

Представим, что это выбор ингредиентов для пиццы. Первая группа - тип теста (тонкое / толстое) - единственный выбор, вторая группа - добавки (сыр, маслины, колбаса и так далее) - множественный выбор.

На данный момент я сделал так: `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`, вывожу через адаптер элементы первой группы с `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`, элементы второй группы - с `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`. Но этого, понятно, недостаточно, так как одиночные элементы всё равно можно выбирать несколько вариантов. Я выкручивался так: у `ListView` по событию `itemClick` проверяю - если элемент из одиночной группы, то снимаю через `setItemChecked` выбор с других элементов. Это работает, список выглядит так, как нужно. Но, происходит странное: `setItemChecked` почему-то даёт задержку! И выбор списка как бы тормозит на полсекунды! То есть, был тип теста Тонкое, ставим Толстое и момент перехода чека подтормаживает... Если `setItemChecked` убрать - никаких тормозов нет. В режиме `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` тоже при переключении радио-кнопок никаких тормозов нет. А вот вручную если - есть!

Вообще, это решение наверняка костыльное и неправильно. Но я не могу найти другого. Словно я первый человек на планете, которому понадобились одиночные и множественные группы в одном `ListView`! Не верю :)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки корректно реализовать задуманное? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам нужен не `ListView`, а `RecylcerView`, он делает то же самое что и обычный `ListView` плюс большую свободу в определении поведения списка и адаптера.
2. Конкретнее, я бы посоветовал взять [Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)
3. Если быть еще точнее, там где нужен множественный выбор то вам нужен `MultiCheckExpandableGroup`, а там где одиночный `SingleCheckExpandableGroup` (это реализовано в указанном виджете)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

1. Не хотелось для небольшого списка использовать RecylcerView.

2. Увы, я работаю в Xamarin и мне тогда придётся портировать решение под него.

Пока решил остаться на своей реализации, обратил внимание, что на других устройствах всё работает отлично, раз нет другого варианта.